# NETGEAR DGN 1000 Limit Usage Per System

Tags: router, internet, modem, qos, resource-usage

How to limit the data usage per system per day connected to my NETGEAR DGN1000 router(modem)?

Please share some ideas. I can also use a dedicated computer if you can propose how to route all the network traffic through that computer. Please note every computer is connected to router via Wi-Fi and router links to Internet(outerworld)

OR is there a way just using router to monitor and/or limit data usage per system per day.

Comment: Is there any way I can setup network monitoring? I want to know the usage per computer connected to my wifi network?

Comment: Sad to see no help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router does not support QoS or any feature that limits usage per system